# Find all directories without r/x permissions for world/other

Tags: linux, permissions, find

I want to find all the directories that that are *not* both readable and executable by the 'others'.  Or put another way, anything where the permissions for 'other' users is anything except `r-x` or `rwx`.

I thought this woud work, but I'm off somehow:

```
find . -type d ! -perm -o+rw
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax will work:

```
find . -type d ! -perm /o+x,o+r
```

Check the examples section of the man page for more info.